# The cup length of an algebra, is it additive?

Tags: algebraic-topology, commutative-algebra, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a graded commutative algebra over a field $k$. The cup length $\DeclareMathOperator{\cl}{cl} \cl(A)$ of $A$ is the largest number of nonzero elements of $A$ of positive degree with nonzero product. Equivalently, $\cl(A)$ the largest number of homogeneous elements of $A$ of positive degree with nonzero product.
If $B$ is an other such $k$-algebra then the tensor product $A\otimes B$ has a k-algebra structure given by
$$
(a\otimes b)\cdot(a'\otimes b') = (-1)^{|a'||b|} aa'\otimes bb'. 
$$
My question is: have we $\cl(A\otimes B) = \cl(A) + \cl(B)$? In an article they said that it is true if A and B are of finite dimension over k, but I don't know why?

Comment: Do mean “dimension over $k$” rather than “number of”? Otherwise , over an infinite field $k$, these are going to be infinite.

Comment: @SammyBlack:  If you consider $k[x]/x^2$ with grading induced by degree, then the cup length is $1$, independent of $k$.  I'm not sure where the cardinality of the field is relevant...

Comment: @JasonDeVito In an article they said that it is true if A and B are of finite dimension over k, but I don't know why?

Comment: I don't have time to think about and (possibly) write an answer, but what I would try first:  Pick $a_i\in A$ with $\Pi a_i\neq 0$ and with the list maximal.  Pick a similar list $b_j$ for $B$, I'd guess that the elements $a_i\otimes 1$ and $1\otimes b_j$ show $cl(A\times B)\geq cl(A)+cl(B)$.  I'm not sure about the reverse inequality

Comment: I realize this is way late, but here's a hint for the reverse inequality.  Start with a list of $c_k\in A\times B$.  Each $c_k$ is sum of pure tensors $c_k = \sum a_{i,k}\otimes b_{i,k}$ where $|a_{i,k}| + |b_{i,k}| = |c_k|$.  If we multiply $N$ of the $c_k$s together, the terms in the answer all involve multiplication of a total of $N$ such pure tensors.  If $N > cl(A) + cl(B)$, then show that such terms involve either more than $cl(A)$ positive degree $a_{i,k}$ or more than $cl(B)$ positive degree $b_{i,k}$.